# Passing page loading time in progress bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, progress-bar, page-load-time

I am having progress bar in my page. It should get display until page loads fully. So I want my progress bar display on page equal to page load time. So I tried to get page load time and pass that time value to display progress bar. I have done coding

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var startTime = new Date().getTime();
    var loadTime;
    function pageload() {
        var endTime = new Date().getTime();
        loadTime = endTime - startTime;
        // alert(loadTime);
    }
    window.onload = function () { pageload(); }
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {

        jQuery('#container').showLoading(
             {
                 'afterShow':
                function () {
                    var a = loadTime;

                    setTimeout("jQuery('#container').hideLoading()", a);

                }
             });
    });
</script>
```

after This change It works !

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var startTime = new Date().getTime();
    var loadTime;
    function pageload() {
        var endTime = new Date().getTime();
        loadTime = endTime - startTime;
        setTimeout("jQuery('#container').hideLoading()", loadTime);
        // alert(loadTime);
    }
    window.onload = function () { pageload(); }
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {

        jQuery('#container').showLoading();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You're trying to use `loadTime` before it's set, as `document.ready` usually executes before `window.onload`. The whole concept of this is flawed, and generally not a good idea.

Comment: Ohk Then tell me.. or suggest me .. how to get page load time value and pass it in progress bar display time. @adeneo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be wrong, but I think you just want to hide it on `onLoad`, like so:

```
jQuery(document).onload(function(){
    jQuery('#container').hideLoading();
});
```

---

**or** put it in your `pageload()` function:

```
function pageload() {
    var endTime = new Date().getTime();
    loadTime = endTime - startTime;
    jQuery('#container').hideLoading();
}
```